# WPF: Turning off animations, data binding temporarly for invisible objects?;)

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a window that contains a tab control - basically multiple sheets with visualizations on them. The visualtizations are:

- possible very resource intensive during rendering
- relying on constant data updates to update their underlying models

Obviously only one sheet can be visible every time ;)

Anyone knows of a good way to turn off all visualization, animations, data binding for a control / panel and it's contained controls? If I would find a way to do that, I could simply turn off all the invisible sheets and reactivate them as needed.

The models must be kept running - some of the visual stuff is pretty complex and really relies on constant data updates, and recalculating it when someone switches tabs would be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see, that the visualization is executed while the control is not visible? I expect that only the operations neccessary for the visible parts are executed, but I'm not sure.

For the case you have to deactivate your animations manually, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294353/wpf-making-an-animations-execution-conditional-on-a-property-of-the-bound-data). I think it should be possible to modify the given example for your requirements.