# Why work only one DataTrigger?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKTbU.png)

```
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HamburgerMenu_IsOpen, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HamburgerMenuRectangles_OpenMenu}"/>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HamburgerMenu_IsOpen, Mode=OneWay}" Value="False">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HamburgerMenuRectangles_CloseMenu}"/>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Only second DataTrigger(CloseMenu) works. If I swap the second(CloseMenu) with the  first(OpenMenu) DataTriggers, then OpenMenu Trigger will works, but Close won't work. I need two triggers to work.

Comment: Try `StopStoryboard` in an `ExitAction` as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1359538/1136211

Comment: This should answer your problem: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444211/datatemplate-multiple-data-triggers-to-same-element-and-property

Answer (score 2):

You bind a single property in two separated `DataTrigger`s, if multiple `DataTrigger`s handle only one dependency property, only the last one works.

It's recommended to merge the two `DataTrigger`s into one.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HamburgerMenu_IsOpen, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HamburgerMenuRectangles_OpenMenu}"/>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HamburgerMenuRectangles_CloseMenu}"/>
        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
    </DataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Then your `EnterActions` will invoke when the value is true and `ExitActions` will invoke when it is false.